# render json data with newlines flask/jinja2

Tags: json, flask, jinja2

I want flask to render a template with a json which includes newlines. However, `JSON.parse()` throws errors. I want to find the best way to deal with this type of information.

Mini sample application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    example = {'blabla': 'what\'s up\n\nnot much'}
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
JSON.parse('{{ some_json_data | tojson }}')
</script>
</body>
</html>
''', some_json_data=example)
```

Combinations I've tried so far:

```
example = {'blabla': 'oh no\n\n'}
JSON.parse('{{ some_json_data | tojson }}')
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 22 of the JSON data

example = {'blabla': 'oh no\n\n'}
JSON.parse('{{ some_json_data | tojson(indent=4) }}')
SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break


example = json.dumps({'blabla': 'what\'s up\n\nnot much'})
JSON.parse('{{ some_json_data }}')
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

example = json.dumps({'blabla': 'what\'s up\n\nnot much'})
JSON.parse('{{ some_json_data | safe }}')
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing this question, I tried even more combinations, and found one that works.

```
example = json.dumps({'blabla': 'what\'s up\n\nnot much'})
JSON.parse({{ some_json_data | tojson }})
```